# Reloading page after successful Facebook Login

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to reload a page using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715047/how-to-reload-a-page-using-javascript)

I have the Facebook login working correctly except for the redirect after the user logs in.

Calling it here:

```
else {
echo '<h3>Please login with your Facebook account</h3>';
echo '<p>';
$f1->displayLoginButton();
echo '</p>';
}
```

$f1->displayLoginButton() defined here:

```
    function displayLoginButton() {
    echo '<fb:login-button show-faces="false" width="600" max-rows="1" scope="publish_stream, manage_pages, email"></fb:login-button>';
}
```

I'm pretty sure I just need to reload the page using something like:

```
window.location.reload()
```

But I'm not too familiar with JS. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715047/how-to-reload-a-page-using-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your `<fb:login-button>` to contain something like this: `onlogin="afterFbLogin()"`, you should have something like this:

```
function displayLoginButton() {
    echo '<fb:login-button show-faces="false" width="600" max-rows="1" scope="publish_stream, manage_pages, email" onlogin="afterFbLogin()"></fb:login-button>';
}
```

What this does is tell FB's API to call `afterFbLogin()` JavaScript function when a user clicks the FB login button. Then simply put the code to reload the window (`window.location.reload(true);`) in that function that should be defined somewhere on your page.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for taking the time to help!!