# Reloading Page Data after PHP Submit

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

ok folks,

I have created a PHP page that is querying a database, and through a whileloop, displays the contents of that database table with a REMOVE and PUSH button.  The REMOVE button removes it from the database entirely, and the PUSH button pushes that entry into another database and sets a variable that the entry has been pushed.

What I'm running into is that I can't quite get the page to refresh, in turn running an new query of the first database and displaying only those entries that have not been removed or pushed.

I can only get the query to run correctly if I manually refresh the page, whether it be F5 or control+r (command+r).

What is the proper way to refresh the page so that the query will run again on page load?

Comment: can we see code, pretty please :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reload the page using Javascript, try this:

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

You can also see this answer:
[How to reload a page using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715047/how-to-reload-a-page-using-javascript)

Comment: It should be window.location.reload(true). window.location.reload(false) loads the page from browser cache which seems like the opposite of what the poster wants.

Comment: Well, the page is reloading, BUT it still won't refresh the query unless I F5 the page.  Any other solutions?

Comment: Without seeing more of your code, I'm not sure I can be much help. If possible, try to simply everything on the page so you can narrow in on what is wrong or causing this weird behavior.

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways

If putting extra load on db is not a problem, use jquery methods likes $.get()

```
$.get('url',{},function(data){
//load results in appropriate div;
});
```

If you don't want to put any extra load on database just hide the row when it is removed or pushed.

```
$('.remove').click(function{
    $(this).css('display','none');
});
```

similarly make it for pushed

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some extreme caching setup on your web hosting solution?

If maintaining nice-looking URLs on this page is a non-issue you could always set a timestamp in PHP and append it to the string.

I'm not big on PHP but a javascript example would look something like this.

```
ts = new Date();
urltorefresh += '?timestamp=' + ts.getTime();
location.href = urltorefresh;
```

This would make sure the page is absolutely not in the browser cache since this specific URL have never been requested before.