# Go back and reload page - one button

Tags: javascript, reload, back, page-refresh

I need to go back on previous page and refresh it. I use history.go(-1) but the form on the previous page is not reloaded.

Thanks for answers.

Comment: Why not just link to the other page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you reopen the page it should automatically refresh. You can probably get the url of the referring page via `document.referrer`
Hope that helps.

Comment: Is there a way to refresh page when I click back button in web browser?

Comment: AFAIK not seamlessly at least, but, there is [`this`](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_The_Back_Button_With_Javascript) article, which might help.

Answer (score 10):

As per 10th June 2014, I have tested latest Chrome 35, FireFox 29 and IE 11. Only Firefox didn't do a reload when I did location.history.back(). So I replaced location.history.back() with

```
location.href = document.referrer
```

So my back button now works like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="location.href = document.referrer; return false;">Back</a>
```

Comment: How about for returning two pages and reload?

Comment: @Pathros Not possible with this method, as document.referrer is only one page back. One idea that comes to mind is using `location.history.back(); location.history.back();` and then a solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715047/how-to-reload-a-page-using-javascript. But I haven't tested it.

Comment: it does indeed refresh the previous page, but still keep the browser history!

Answer (score 1):

I think I invented a way of doing this. By adding a random parameter to url, we force browser to refresh...

```
var backLocation = document.referrer;
if (backLocation) {
    if (backLocation.indexOf("?") > -1) {
        backLocation += "&randomParam=" + new Date().getTime();
    } else {
        backLocation += "?randomParam=" + new Date().getTime();
    }
    window.location.assign(backLocation);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

on the previous page use the following

```
 <% Response.AddHeader "Pragma", "no-cache" %>
  <% Response.Expires = -1 %>
```

in case of asp

in addition check [this](http://lab.artlung.com/anti-cache/)

Comment: look at the link that I gave , it has multiple combos for different languages