# JQuery Ajax post not redirecting when ActionResult returned from MVC controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am attempting to post data from a method to an MVC controller that returns an action result, and have my site redirect to the correct view.  The code I am attempting to use is below.

```
function KoJqRedirect(item, url, async) {
$.ajax({
    type: "Post",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: ko.toJSON(item),
    async: async,
    url: url,
    success: function () { return false; }
});
```

}

The controller is posted to correctly and returns the view, the problem is that the page is not displayed.  How would i go about getting this page to display when returned to the success function?

Comment: you are returning partialview from controller action????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show html returning from controller action then do as :

```
function KoJqRedirect(item, url, async) {
  $.ajax({
   type: "post",
   contentType: "application/json",
   data: ko.toJSON(item),
   datatype :'html', //give datatype here
   async: async,
   url: url,
   success: function (data) { 
     $("#div1").html(data); //provide target div id here 
   }
 });
}
```

Comment: need to wait another 7 seconds

Comment: what if I want a full page reload?

Comment: @j-j, you can reload the page using JS. Refer this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715047/how-to-reload-a-page-using-javascript