# Do we have router.reload in vue-router?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vue-router, reload

I see in this [pull request](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/pull/442):

> - Add a `router.reload()`
>
>   Reload with current path and call data hook again

But when I try issuing the following command from a Vue component:

```
this.$router.reload()
```

I get this error:

> `Uncaught TypeError: this.$router.reload is not a function`

I searched in the [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-link.html?q=reload), but could not found anything relevant. Does vue/vue-router provider some functionality like this?

The software versions I'm interested in are:

```
"vue": "^2.1.0",
"vue-router": "^2.0.3",
```

PS. I know `location.reload()` is one of the alternatives, but I'm looking for a native Vue option.

Comment: Why would you reload it anyway? The reactivity is supposed to do its job for you. It's also quite similar to [Can you force Vue.js to reload/re-render?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32106155/8816585).

Answer (score 275):

`this.$router.go()` does exactly this; if no arguments are specified, the router navigates to current location, refreshing the page.

> note: current [implementation of router](http://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/src/index.js#L175) and [its history components](http://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/src/history/html5.js#L40) don't mark the param as optional, but IMVHO it's either a bug or an omission on Evan You's part, since [the spec explicitly allows it](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/go#Parameters). [I've filed an issue report about it.](http://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/3065) If you're really concerned with current TS annotations, just use the equivalent `this.$router.go(0)`

As to 'why is it so': `go` internally passes its arguments to `window.history.go`, so its equal to `windows.history.go()` - which, in turn, reloads the page, as per [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History).

> note: since this executes a "soft" reload on regular desktop (non-portable) Firefox, a bunch of strange quirks may appear if you use it but in fact you require a true reload; using the `window.location.reload(true);` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload) mentioned by OP instead may help - it certainly did solve my problems on FF.

Comment: Yes, it's doing a page refresh and not a component reload.

Comment: <span @click="()=>{this.$router.go()}" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger">

Comment: Note that `$router.go()` accepts one parameter, so you should use it as `$router.go(0)`, meaning _navigate zero pages back in history_

Comment: @Dan FWIW, I'd say the fact that both https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/src/index.js#L175 & it's implementations (e.g. https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/src/history/html5.js#L40) don't mark the param as optional is either a bug or an omission on Evan You's part, since the spec explicitly allows it (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/go#Parameters). I've filed a bug report about it @ https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/3065, though.

Comment: `window.location.reload(forceReload)` seems to be deprecated, but `window.location.reload()` is ok.

Comment: all answers here are wrong, go without param is not allowed, also go(0) is not working, same error.

Comment: location.reload(); Work for me in typescript.

Comment: it doesn't work with safari

Comment: For people coming here, vue confirmed themselves there is *no* reload. This answer might've worked at the time, but is no longer accurate.

Comment: This worked fine in my Vue3 application using composition API:

`import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';`, `const router = useRouter();`, `router.go(0);`

Answer (score 85):

The simplest solution is to add a `:key` attribute to `<router-view>`:

```html
<router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
```

This is because Vue Router does not notice any change if the same component is being addressed. With the key, any change to the path will trigger a reload of the component with the new data.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#key in the official docs indirectly explains the mechanism of the key special attribute in vue.

Comment: This will not work, because in the scenario the OP is discussing the full path will not change.

Comment: Worked great for me. Upvoted this answer.

Comment: finally I know what the key is used for.. Thank you this solved my problem

Comment: when `router-view` is used in combination with `keep-alive` then the `key` must be placed on `component` itself, as stated in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66215625/vue-3-keep-alive-cache-routes

Answer (score 53):

```
this.$router.go(this.$router.currentRoute)
```

---

Vue-Router Docs:

I checked vue-router repo on GitHub and it seems that there isn't `reload()` method any more. But in the same file, there is: `currentRoute` object.

Source: [vue-router/src/index.js](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/src/index.js#L82) 
Docs: [docs](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/8bdabc772065fbcba9c59318f07c09bf45769c12/docs/en/api/router-instance.md#routercurrentroute)

```
get currentRoute (): ?Route {
    return this.history && this.history.current
  }
```

Now you can use `this.$router.go(this.$router.currentRoute)` for reload current route.

Simple [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eBaEPw).

Version for this answer:

```
"vue": "^2.1.0",
"vue-router": "^2.1.1"
```

Comment: This won't refresh any data on `Safari`

Comment: Is there a way to just reload the component, without refreshing the page ?
The route should be same, let's say '/users'. But when i click on refresh button, it has to refresh the entire page, without reloading the page.

Comment: @Rajeshwar give a `:key` value to the component and change the value when you want to reload that component. This will trigger beforeDestroy() and start the component lifecycle from the beginning.

Answer (score 14):

Use `router.go(0)` if you use Typescript, and it's asking arguments for the go method.

Comment: How is it related to TS here? You don't even specify any kind of type.

Answer (score 9):

router.js

```
routes: [
{
  path: '/',
  component: test,
  meta: {
    reload: true,
  },
}]
```

main.js

```
import router from './router';

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
  router,
  watch:{
    '$route' (to) {
       if(to.currentRoute.meta.reload==true){window.location.reload()}
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: Ah, but this actually reloads the browser window. I think most people here are interested in maintaining the SPA, just re-rendering the current route (view).

Comment: to.currentRoute is undefined in my application, but to.meta did the trick! Great

Answer (score 6):

Resolve the route to a URL and navigate the window with Javascript.

```js
        let r = this.$router.resolve({
        name: this.$route.name, // put your route information in
        params: this.$route.params, // put your route information in
        query: this.$route.query // put your route information in
      });
      window.location.assign(r.href)
```

This method replaces the URL and causes the page to do a full request (refresh) rather than relying on Vue.router. $router.go does not work the same for me even though it is theoretically supposed to.

Answer (score 6):

A simple example:

```
this.$router.go(0)
```

Here is docs:
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#traverse-history

Answer (score 3):

```html
<router-link 
  :to='`/products`'
  @click.native="$router.go()"
  class="sub-link"
>
</router-link>
```

I have tried this for reloading the current page.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution if you just want to update certain components on a page:

In template

```
<Component1 :key="forceReload" />
<Component2 :key="forceReload" />
```

In data

```
data() {
  return {
    forceReload: 0
  {
}
```

In methods:

```
   Methods: {
     reload() {
        this.forceReload += 1
     }
   }
```

Use a unique key and bind it to a data property for each one you want to update (I typically only need this for a single component, two at the most. If you need more, I suggest just refreshing the full page using the other answers.

I learned this from Michael Thiessen's post:
https://medium.com/hackernoon/the-correct-way-to-force-vue-to-re-render-a-component-bde2caae34ad

Answer (score 2):

It's my reload. Because of some browser very weird. `location.reload` can't reload.

```js
methods:{
   reload: function(){
      this.isRouterAlive = false
      setTimeout(()=>{
         this.isRouterAlive = true
      },0)
   }
}
```

```html
<router-view v-if="isRouterAlive"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function removeHash () { 
    history.pushState("", document.title, window.location.pathname
                                          + window.location.search);
}


App.$router.replace({name:"my-route", hash: '#update'})
App.$router.replace({name:"my-route", hash: ' ', params: {a: 100} })
setTimeout(removeHash, 0)
```

Notes:

1. And the `#` must have some value after it.
2. The second route hash is a space, not empty string.
3. `setTimeout`, not `$nextTick` to keep the url clean.

Answer (score 1):

For rerender you can use in parent component

```html
<template>
  <div v-if="renderComponent">content</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
   data() {
      return {
        renderComponent: true,
      };
    },
    methods: {
      forceRerender() {
        // Remove my-component from the DOM
        this.renderComponent = false;
        
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          // Add the component back in
          this.renderComponent = true;
        });
      }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple reload/refresh any component do below things

```
<ProductGrid v-if="renderComponent"/>

<script>
import ProductGrid from "./product-grid";
export default {
  name:'product',
  components: {
    ProductGrid
  },
  data() {
    return {
      renderComponent: true,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    forceRerender: function() {
      // Remove my-component from the DOM
        this.renderComponent = false;
        this.$nextTick(() => {
            // Add the component back in
            this.renderComponent = true;
        });
    }
 },
 watch:{
    '$route.query.cid'(newId, oldId) {
        if(newId>0){
            this.forceRerender();
        }      
     }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to go to reload same route from same source on vue router 4:

```
import {
  useRouter,
  NavigationFailureType,
  isNavigationFailure,
} from "vue-router";

const router = useRouter();
const handleLinkClick = (link) => {
  router.push({ name: link }).then((failure) => {
    if (isNavigationFailure(failure, NavigationFailureType.duplicated)) {
      router.go({ name: link });
    }
  });
```

[source](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-failures.html#detecting-navigation-failures)

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73151062/4759176) helped me:

```
 this.$router
          .push({ path: '/home' })
          .then(() => { this.$router.go() })
```

It first redirects to `/home` and then reloads the page. Helps with getting updated navbar after login.

Answer (score 0):

I have two way to reload route.

### 1. Refresh with a second blank page.

if we want to refresh page A.

```js
 // at A page, go to blank page
 route.push('/blank')
 // at black page, go to A page
 route.push('/A')
```

### 2. use `v-if` refresh route

- js

```js
  // at vue3 
  const componentVisible = ref(true)

  const refresh = () => {
    componentVisible.value = false
    nextTick(() => {
      componentVisible.value = true
    })
  }
```

- template

```js
<button @click="refresh">click to reload</button>

<div v-if="componentVisible" class="panel-content">
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

if you mean to reload the page just do:

```
window.location.reload()
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! I would recommend looking at @Enver's answer though, and either editing Enver's answer or addressing the concerns in the comments in your answer.

Answer (score -4):

```
vueObject.$forceUpdate();
```

You could use the `forceUpdate` method.

Answer (score -5):

```
window.location.reload();
```

You can use it to reload your current page. There is similar usage in Jquery too.

Comment: Re-loading the window is the opposite of what one wants to achieve with a PWA. So although the solution technically solves the problem, it is not a useful solution for the problem at hand.

Comment: @Fred you probably meant SPA here (rather than PWA). And yep, it's indeed a quite bad practice for such purpose because it's nukes the whole Vue app.

Comment: The thing is that we're not using jQuery but Vue here, quite important detail.