# Vuejs route navigation guard on async auth state request

Tags: javascript, vue.js, firebase-authentication, vue-router, vuex

I'm using firebase to do authentication in my vuejs app. In my root (main.js) vue component.

```
  created() {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      this.$store.commit('user/SET_USER', user);
      if (user && user.emailVerified) {
        this.$store.dispatch('user/UPDATE_VERIFIED', {
          userId: user.uid,
        });
        // SUCCESSFUL LOGIN
        this.$router.replace('dashboard');
      } else if (user && !user.emailVerified) {
        this.$router.replace('verify');
      }
    });
```

So essentially, my router navigation guard is checking auth status and doing routing before each route as well.

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const currentUser = firebaseApp.auth().currentUser;
  const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth);
  const allowUnverified = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.allowUnverified);

  if (requiresAuth && !currentUser) {
    next('login');
  } else if (currentUser
              && !currentUser.emailVerified
              && !allowUnverified
              && to.path !== '/verify') {
    next('verify');
  } else if (!requiresAuth && currentUser) {
    next('dashboard');
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

What happens is, when you refresh the page (with a valid auth token), you hit branch 1 of the route guard, stateChanges and the handler is called to redirect to /dashboard. So refreshing while logged in, always brings you to the dashboard route instead of the current route youre on.

How can I handle this case? Adding a beforeEnter guard to each auth component smells bad to me [Data Fetching Vue Docs](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/data-fetching.html).

Should this be in the store instead of the created hook on the root instance? Any help is greatly appreciated. This pattern is stumping me.

Comment: I would put the auth logic in a service like module, remove all of the routing from that logic and just handle routing in the router, where you're already doing most of it (in the navigation guard).

Comment: @frank I feel like the firebase tags are irrelevant to this question.

Comment: I merely replaced the generic [firebase] with the more specific [firebase-authentication], which is what OP is using here. Feel free to make any edits you think improve the chances of it getting answered.

Comment: @EmileBergeron but routing and auth need to be aware of each other. If auth state goes to "unauthorized" then route needs to go back to login.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Quick fix

If the user exists and doesn't require authentication, why redirect him to another page (the dashboard)?

```
  } else if (!requiresAuth && currentUser) {
    next('dashboard');
  } else {
    next();
  }
```

You could just let the routing continue.

```
  if (requiresAuth && !currentUser) {
    next('login');
  } else if (requiresAuth && !currentUser.emailVerified && !allowUnverified) {
    next('verify');
  } else {
    next();
  }
```

You'd also need to remove `this.$router.replace('dashboard');` from the `onAuthStateChanged` callback. See below for a more in depth answer.

## In depth

I would avoid putting *authentication* and *routing* logic in Vue components. While it may someday makes sense, in this case, it can be totally avoided.

I like to put the Vuex store instance in an isolated module so I can use it elsewhere, not limited to Vue.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
// Configuration is generated with a function, so testing the store is easier
import getConfig from './config';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store(getConfig());
```

So auth logic could be moved to a `auth.js` service.

```
import store from './store';
import router from './router';

// other auth related code, you can even export a common API
// to use within your app.
// like this simple wrapper, which hides the fact that you're using firebase
export function getUser() {
  return firebaseApp.auth().currentUser;
}
export default { getUser }

auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  // store/business logic should be inside the store.
  store.dispatch('user/AUTH_STATE_CHANGED', user);
  // minimal handling of mandatory steps in the login or sign up process
  if (!user) {
     router.push('login');
  } else if (user && !user.emailVerified) {
    router.push('verify');
  }
});
```

If the user is correctly logged in, there is no reason to redirect here. Since the global navigation guard is going to do most of the redirection work, you could just [redirect to the current route with `router.go()` or `router.push(router.currentRoute)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41301099/1218980).

In fact, this navigation guard could be registered inside the `auth.js` service mentioned above.

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const currentUser = getUser();
  const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth);
  const allowUnverified = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.allowUnverified);

  if (requiresAuth && !currentUser) {
    next('login');
  } else if (requiresAuth && !currentUser.emailVerified && !allowUnverified) {
    next('verify');
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

And then, add simple navigation guards to routes which shouldn't be reachable once logged in.

```
path: '/login',
beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
    if (auth.getUser()) {
        next('dashboard');
    } else {
        next();
    }
},
```

The point is: **only force a redirect when navigating to a restricted page.**

When a logged in user refreshes the page, there are no reason to redirect to `/dashboard`. If that same user would try to navigate to login, then there is a reason to redirect to `/dashboard`.

Comment: What to do if getUser returned null? This happens when the auth module didn't verify user yet, but `beforeEach` callbacks were called. How to wait for user authentication and showing the load page all this time?