# How do I reload the web app when current route link is clicked again?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Please take a look at the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/L3px7okf/

I want to reload the app when the same route (for example `/foo`) which you are currently on is clicked again because I need to reset the page state (yes, the correct way would be, actually, to reset the state, but the application code is a bit tricky thus I need a quick solution).

But I don't want to reload the app when I'm clicking `/foo` being on route `/bar`.

The problem is that `VueRouter` does nothing when the same link is clicked. Global (like `beforeEach`) and in-component (like `beforeRouterEnter`/`beforeRouteLeave`) hooks are not called. `@onclick.native` event handling doesn't help because when the handler is executed the route is already updated.

Answer (score 0):

I found this...https://stackoverflow.com/a/51170320/10039548

`<router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>`

Seems like they talk a bit about this issue here

Comment: No, it is said "With the key, any change to the path will trigger a reload of the component with the new data". Thus, this still requires URL modification.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.$router.go()
```

Can refresh the page on click..

Comment: what about `/bar->/foo`? as I've described in this case I don't want to reload the app.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<a href="your route here">` I've used this and it's working just fine.