# Nuxt.js: how to redirect inside methods

Tags: vue.js, routes, nuxt.js

I'm learning Nuxt.js and I'm puzzled by how difficult it seems to be to simply redirect a user to another page from a method that is triggered via a click.

Here is the set up: I'm using Nuxt Auth to authenticate users, once authenticated I want them to be forwarded away from the signup page to another route. I already have middleware set up that redirect logged-in users, but it is only triggered when I refresh the page, not when I first log them in.

I have a method like this:

```
async login(event) {
   event.preventDefault()
   try {
      await this.$auth.loginWith('local', this.loginData)
      // this is where my redirect logic should go
   } catch(error) { ... }
}
```

So far I've tried using `this.$nuxt.refresh()` which doesn't do anything at all and I've also tried `this.$router.push('/route')` which seems to hang the page completely. Ideally, I would prefer the `refresh` approach so that I don't have to specify the landing page for logged in users in multiple places, but I also need to know how to use redirections inside methods, I would have thought it should be the most simple operation imaginable and yet it seems to be difficult to find.

Any tips would be highly appreciated!

UPDATE:

I've found a solution, although it's not an ideal one. I've added an if-statement into `beforeCreate` that checks `this.$auth.loggedIn` and if it's true, then it calls `this.$auth.redirect('home')` when "home" is defined in `nuxt.config.js` under auth redirect. The reason this solution is not ideal is that it relies on the auth module (as opposed to being a general redirect mechanism).

Answer (score 0):

There's a way in Nuxt to reload the page like so:

```
this.$router.go(0)
```

also you can find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41301099/do-we-have-router-reload-in-vue-router)

Answer (score 0):

if `this.$router` is not working, try this

```
this.$nuxt.$options.router.push(url);
```