# Redirect with page reload Vue JS Router

Tags: vue.js

I have an app with a Login.vue and Home.vue files. Because I converted an admin HTML website to a vue 3 app, my javascript only works with page reload. When creating the app I selected add router for SPA maybe I shouldn't have. Up to this point, the views are working except when I redirect from login to home without reloading. Since it is not reloading, my navbar or any JS-dependent functions won't work. how do I redirect from login to home with page reload? Currently, I have the below code but still not working.

```
this.$router.push({
      path: "/admin/home",
      reload: true
    });
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `this.$router.go(0)` to reload the page. You need the `0` if you use Typescript as mentioned by @Second2None. In combination with `this.$router.push({ path: '/some/path' })` you can achieve it without directly changing the browser's window property.

```html
<template>
  <button @click="redirectReload">Redirect & Reload</button>
</template>
    
<script>
  export default {  
    methods: {
      redirectReload() {
        this.$router
          .push({ path: '/expedition' })
          .then(() => { this.$router.go(0) })
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Notice how I used `.then` after `$router.push()`. Because the `push()` method is asynchronous, the reload would happen before the route change without `then()`.

As a bonus, it lets you use all the features of $router.push (for example using arguments like `{ name: 'home' }`.

---

Example with Composition API and async/await syntax:

```html
<script setup>

import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'
const router = useRouter()

const redirectReload = async () => {
  await router.push({ path: '/expedition' })
  router.go(0)
}

</script>
```

---

### Update

I recommend checking out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41301099/13182129) thread as there are answers that describe how to reload the page component without reloading the whole website using the `:key` prop and other useful information.

Comment: Thank you for the response did the trick.

Comment: I spent a couple hours troubleshooting why the template section of my login page wasn't rendering when I redirected to it using <RouterLink to="/login">Continue to the login page</RouterLink>. This solved my issue. I don't understand why but it works

Comment: For anyone using 'script setup' I did it like this: import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'; const router = useRouter(); const redirectReload = ()=> {
    router
    .push({ path: '/login' })
    .then(()=> { router.go() })
}

Comment: @ToddHammer your app probably had some problems with component update order. Better to fix that without using crutches like reloading the whole SPA. You better create a new question with more details and ping me

Comment: If you are using typescript `router.go()` throws an error:  `Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554)` to fix this you can just do  `router.go(0)` for reload.

Answer (score 2):

Vue Router not reload page when you navigate to new URL.

You can try this code for you issue:

```
const url = new URL('/admin/home', window.location.origin)
window.location.href = url.toString()
```

Hope this help