# Can i force reload/re-render particular url in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

Is it possible if, when i go to the url "example.com/abc", the page should for reload instead of dom update. For other urls it should be normal. For /abc the page should for reload/re-render.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do we have router.reload in vue-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41301099/do-we-have-router-reload-in-vue-router)

Comment: Why do you want to nuke your SPA? Don't want to have something performant while keeping the state?

Comment: @kissu why are you having problem of my every question? You want me to stop asking questions on SO?

Comment: I'm voting to close your question and asking for some feedback because your questions are not following the rules here indeed. Please read how to ask a proper question, with enough context, details and without asking people to code something for you. Overall, put in more effort. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You Can use location.reload();
If Not Work Then Place It in OnMounted hooks.

Comment: Nope, don't do this please.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).