# How to reload the same route in vue 3 (vue-router 4)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, vue-router4

I encountered a curious case during development.

I have a **modal component** that warns users about a change in price: 
*If a user clicks the button I want the page to reload and automatically run the **onMounted** hook, after that calculate a new price inside the hook with an apiCall*.

The behavior I encountered is that nothing changes about the page and the modal remains open like it's ignoring the **router.push()** method.

I wanted to implement this solution in Vue 3 and understand why **router.push() doesn't work**.
I found a workaround with window.location.href but I'd love to hear the reason why using the standard router is not allowing me to succed with the standard vue-router.

> I am inside the route /payment?code=123&hash=123, the object ***routerEnums.PAYMENT*** is equal to ***'/payment'***, It works fine with any other route except this one.

```
/**script**/

import {useRouter} from "vue-router"; 
const router = useRouter();

/**template**/

<change-price-modal-good
    v-if="showModalPriceChange"
    @price-change-button-clicked="router.push(routerEnums.PAYMENT)"
/>
```

Comment: The [question was asked on GitHub](https://github.com/vuejs/router/issues/1257) in the Vue Router repository, similar to yours.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you would like to reload, and I found [relevant content about this on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41301099/do-we-have-router-reload-in-vue-router).

Comment: @rozsazoltan yes but also no, I'd like to reload the route but this time without the queryString attached, the router.go(0) would be perfect if I had the possibility to modify the pathName

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation says to `router.push()`:

> This method pushes a new entry into the history stack, so when the
> user clicks the browser back button they will be taken to the previous
> URL. This is the method called internally when you click a tag
> router-link, so clicking `router-link :to="..."` is the equivalent of
> calling `router.push(...)`.

You can also put some properties to the `router.push()` as path or name, params, query, hash, etc.

If you want to reload a component use `router.go(0)`. You can find more information on the [link here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the only problem is I want to reload the page but without the queryParams, do you know if it's achievable anyway with the vue-router?
I edited the question.

Comment: Well, router.go(0) only takes last URL and reload it, so it means with the params. If you want to delete them, you should use router.push({ path: '/payment', params: { } }); It works fine for me. Does it help to you too?

Comment: I have also edited the answer, may it is better to use query: {} except params: {} inside the method. The query will delete everything behind the question mark, while params contains other URL parts divided by slash.

Comment: I found a way to make it work, basically I push the "vanilla" route inside the router and then I call router.go(0) this way the reload is successful, still I don't really know if it's the best way around.
Also i added a key in the template of the page which is changed when i click the button

Answer (score 0):

If the reason behind the page reload is to run `onMounted` again, it can be achieved without reloading the whole app. You can set a key on the `<router-view>` that renders the component with `route.fullPath` as value. On router push the key will change forcing the remount of the component.

```
<router-view :key="route.fullPath"></router-view>

setup(){
  const route = useRoute()

  return {
    route
  }
}
```

Also, you can use a computed key, and change it only for the desired route, returning a default key for the rest of the routes.