Handling timeout for proper redirect. Simultanious redirect and reload issues
I've implemented a timeout to show a modal and then redirect the user after a delay. Specifically, I’m having trouble with the page reload and redirect behavior. During the delay, if the user clicks a different link by accident, it should cancel the redirection and handle the new navigation properly.
let timeoutId = null;
const isRedirecting = ref(false);

const handleSignOut = async () => {
    if (pending.value || isRedirecting.value) return;

    await signOut();
    if (successMessage.value && !isOpen.value) {
        isOpen.value = true;
        isRedirecting.value = true;
        timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
            isOpen.value = false;
            navigateTo('/'); // Redirect after 3 seconds
            isRedirecting.value = false;
        }, 3000);
    }
};

watch(route, () => {
    if (timeoutId) {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    }
});

Another problem is that when a user clicks the "Sign Out" button, the button state changes immediately without reloading the entire page. This behavior looks unnatural, as most websites typically reload the page upon sign-out so that UI elements are properly updated. Besides, on some websites, after signing out, users are often redirected to an intermediary page like "Signing Out..." before being redirected to the homepage.
Reproduction: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-rpcn41?file=app%2Fpages%2Fsign-in.vue
Looking for a possible solution.

if you have anchor-tagged page sections, reloading 0 will scroll to the same page section.  Other than that I couldn't say.  That page delay you said your animations take 300ms but you only have 150 time delay.

@JohnLord Yeah, because 300/2 = 150, so in the middle of the animation I want the page to reload, so that it's not visible to the user.

it's not going to keep animating while the page is reloading.  You need to finish the animation first.

@JohnLord I still don't understand why I appear not at top on redirect&reload. For example, I'm currently at the top of /gallery and I click sign out. In 300ms I appear at 50% of the page at '/' for some reason. It doesn't happen when I just change the route, it's something that's wrong with the code inside handleSignOut

is your historic url showing a \ in it?  In our project, we purposefully strip parameters off of the url.  It must be something like this or you would end up half way down the page when you initially load it.

@JohnLord What is a historic url? Something weird is happening to Nitro. I just reloaded the project 2 times and it starts to work properly. I'm not sure if it's a Nuxt bug or something else.

What is the role of router.go(0) here? What happens if you don't use this? It's similar to location.reload() which were used in the previous question, and there should be real reasons to use it in an SPA.

@EstusFlask If I just do navigateTo('/') it won't update the ui, which means after signing out I'll still see the sign out button. It's because signedIn is a ref that depends on cookie. If I click on sign out it removes the cookie and sets signedIn to false, but I need to reload the page to see the change and so that the buttons change naturally along with the whole page and not separately. That's why I use reload.go(0), which reloads the page. I found out about it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41301099/do-we-have-router-reload-in-vue-router

This sounds like XY problem. Reloading a page in SPA is almost always the last resort to fix an app that wasn't properly designed. Shouldn't be a problem if you control the way the app works. That you have a problem suggests that reactivity doesn't work. There wasn't a hint that there's a problem with signedIn reactivity in the previous demo. Probably it was incorrectly synchronized with a cookie, or else

@EstusFlask If I don't reload the page it means only the buttons will change when I sign out, but the rest of the UI will stay and it's going to look strange. In my case, the header and the footer don't transition when I switch between routes, because it's a nuxt layout . The content in </slot> is that's what transition applies to. The header will only transition if I go to the route with another layout, that's why I have pageTransition and layoutTransition set up in nuxt.config.ts. My design in slightly different from most websites.

I see. What is "the rest of the UI" exactly and how is it connected to auth state? Can you update the demo to reflect this?

@EstusFlask Sure, I'll try to update the demo. The rest of the UI is the rest of the buttons in a header where I have sign in link which leads to /sign in page, also sign out button and the main content in </slot>. Usually, when I sign out on most websites, the page is reloaded.

@EstusFlask Here's the updated repro:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-rpcn41?file=app%2Fpages%2Fsign-in.vue. To test, click on the 'Sign in' button and you'll be sent to a page with an auth layout. Then, click on the 'sign into your account' and wait for 3 sec so it redirects you to '/'. Now if click on 'Sign out', you'll see that only the button changes and it looks strange to me, because usually a page should be refreshed when you sign out.

@EstusFlask Another problem here is, if clicking on Go to about in the modal during these 3 sec, it redirects to '/about' and then immediately to '/' after a 3-second timeout. I tried to solve this using an isRedirecting ref and clearing the timer, but it didn't work. This detail matters because popular sites usually cancel the redirection if the user clicks another link during the timeout. I'm unsure if this should be handled manually or if there's a plugin that manages it, but this is how I attempted to fix it.

It seems to work ok without router.go? https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-jzbmor . As for redirects, the problem is that you try to handle this watch(route in component instance that has been already unmounted, while a timeout still exists and causes memory leak. You could store a timeout and some of redirect logic in "auth" store to persist through the app and potentially handle in router hooks. Or let a modal's parent handle the navigation to /about instead of using  inside modal. But it looks like clearTimeout inside onUnmounted would solve this

@EstusFlask it does work without router.go, but I want the whole page to refresh, instead of just buttons, because that's how most websites work. Take a look at the Rockstar Games login for example. They either refresh the page or redirect you to some other page where it says 'Wait please...' and then send you back to home. I've never seen a website where I click 'sign out' and nothing but the button changes, looks unnatural to me. You're right, onUnmounted worked! I can now remove the watch. I basically just put  inside modal to demonstrate the issue with redirect and timeout.

@EstusFlask @EstusFlask maybe I'll just use the same approach as Rockstar does - sending a user to intermediary page where it says 'Signing Out...' and then use a timed redirect, because it looks like it's not an easy task in Nuxt/Vue to force refresh the page without consequences. Someone on Discord recommended me to use reloadNuxtApp instead, but that's just funny. If you know a better way besides creating an intermediary page, please leave an answer below so I can upvote it. This way, you’ll get some rep for the help. I appreciate it .

@EstusFlask I changed the question and the title to the current one, since the original question was resolved by simply rebooting the project and is not useful.

" but I want the whole page to refresh, instead of just buttons, because that's how most websites work." - this is so for MPA apps, but you're using SPA framework and have SPA app, it's weird and inefficient to do a full reload in this case. When the app is properly engineered with SPA in mind, there are zero problems with updating app state on log in/out without a reload

@EstusFlask I see, didn't know about that. Thanks for letting me know.

I suppose the most websites where you could see the approach you're after are not the state-of-the-art but MPAs with limitations. If you want an intermediate screen for some reason, you can implement it, but regarding UI/UX I'd suggest to investigate the real cases further, specifically SPA apps. IMO it's perfectly ok to log in/out a user with no fireworks or like that. Generally you just update top menu with current auth state and redirect to / if a user was at auth-only route, and that's it. The most visual thing I could think of is a "logging out" modal, and make it last at least for 1-2s

@EstusFlask I think the idea of "logging out" modal is great. I'll also look into other SPA apps to get inspiration. Thank you.

by historic url, i mean when you pass (0) you are saying give me the most recent url in the browser's history.  The bigger the number you enter, the farther back in history you get a url from.

@JohnLord I see, thanks for clarifying. When setting router.go(0) it just reloads the current page.

You can handle redirections inside the current tab using Nuxt's "onBeforeRouteLeave" by doing this
onBeforeRouteLeave(() => {
if (-your not redirect conditions-) {
  return false
}})

on the other hand, you can put a location.reload() on you singOUt function to do a reload in your page
