# setTimeout() not working called from vueJS method

Tags: javascript, methods, vue.js

I am trying to allow a user to reset or shutdown a given server from an app.  Im working on the interface right now, and want to give the user messages as to what is happening.  I display a message defined in my data object to indicate the action taken.  I then use setTimeout to switch a resetting.... message with a reset message.  See the following method.

```
    systemReset: function(){
            this.message = this.server + ': Resetting';
            setTimeout(function(){
                this.message = this.server + ': Reset';
            }, 2000);
            
    }
```

In my browser I can trigger this message and my message of "Resetting" displays, but the following "Reset" message is never output.  Do I have any formatting errors?

To put this method in context here is my entire component.

```
  <template>
    <div>
      <p>{{message}}</p>
      <button @click="systemReset">Reset Server</button>
      <button @click="systemPowerDown">Poweroff Server</button>
    </div>
  </template>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    export default{
      data: function(){
        return{
          message: ''
        }
      },
      methods: {
        systemPowerDown: function(){
            this.message = this.server + ': Server Down';
        },
        systemReset: function(){
            this.message = this.server + ': Resetting';
            setTimeout(function(){
                this.message = this.server + ': Reset';
            }, 2000);
         }
      },
      props: ['server']
    }
  </script>

Am I missing something obvious?  Or is there some vue limitation I am unaware of?
```

Comment: `this.message` is a string, how and when are you showing it?

Comment: Could it be down to using `this` keyword within the timeout function, so it is referring to the timeout function instead of systemReset?

Comment: Im outputting it in my paragraph

Comment: But only once ..?

Comment: @PatrickMcDermott Maybe, does that happen?

Comment: Yeah, you need to make sure you store reference to the function. Examples and explanation in answers. @TommyBrunn has provided a good explanation

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The value of `this` is different inside the `setTimeout`.

If you're using ES6, you can use an arrow function:

```
setTimeout(() => { this.message = this.server + ': Reset' }, 2000)
```

Or if you're not, you can bind the value of `this`:

```
setTimeout(function () {
  this.message = this.server + ': Reset'
}.bind(this))
```

However, having never used Vue, I don't know if it will know to re-render when you change the value of `this.message`, or if you should be changing some component state or something.

Comment: In case anyone is curious, Vue does know to re-render when the value changes when using `bind(this)`.

Comment: You are the savior. bind(this) is the whole thing. Thank you so much

Answer (score 6):

Because you're inside a `setTimeout`, `this` doesn't correspond with your Vue instance. You can use `self` instead :

```
systemReset: function(){
    this.message = this.server + ': Resetting';
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
        self.message = self.server + ': Reset';
    }, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Could be solved of storing `this` in a variable out of the timeout function?

Like so:

```
 systemReset: function(){
            var $this = this;
            $this.message = this.server + ': Resetting';
            setTimeout(function(){
                $this.message = this.server + ': Reset';
            }, 2000);
         }
```

Doing so refers to the correct function `systemReset`

Answer (score 0):

I had a familiar problem.
So the solution was to create a function (in 'methods') that changed the variable.
Then from the 'setInterval' I called this method (this.methodname).

Answer (score 0):

**Use $forceUpdate()** if nothing helped.

The appropriate passage of `this` to setTimeout() works fine in JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/BeloglazovRL/owL94phz/ (Vue 2.6.14).
But it doesn't work with my web application which use Vue 2.6.13.

Call to Vue `this.$forceUpdate();` helped me with a periodically called `setTimeout()`.

I have tired all other answers: saving `this` to `self`, arrow function and explicit bind.
The debug output prints changing variable and correct `this` with Vue inner stuff, but nothing was changing on the screen. It changed only after the timer ends.
I tried set timeout to 5 seconds instead 1 second. It didn't help too.
Then I decided to force update. E.g.: [Can you force Vue.js to reload/re-render?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32106155/can-you-force-vue-js-to-reload-re-render)

It helped me do solve the problem. So you have to use the code like this:

```
myTimer() {

  ... //Change text, e.g.: %, timer and so on. Check condition for halt.

  this.vueTextVar = newTextValue;
  this.$forceUpdate();
  setTimeout(() => {
          this.myTimer();
        }, 1000);
}
```