# How do I use setTimeout in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to Vue.js. How do I use the setTimeout in Vue.js?

Here is where I want to timeout

```
dataReq.end((err, resp) => {
            resp = JSON.parse(resp.text)
            if (resp.status) {
              setTimeout(this.$router.push, 10000)(this.breadcrumbs[2].path)
            }
          })
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setTimeout() not working called from vueJS method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45301063/settimeout-not-working-called-from-vuejs-method)

Answer (score 0):

You shold b doing it like this:

```
dataReq.end((err, resp) => {
        resp = JSON.parse(resp.text)
        if (resp.status) {
          setTimeout(() => {
              this.$router.push(this.breadcrumbs[2].path);
          }, 10000)
        }
      })
```

`setTimeout` takes a function to be executed after timeout as 1st argument and `$router.push()` takes the path as an argument ,, guessing `this.breadcrumbs[2].path` is a valid path

Comment: @user2486 that's the reason i am using an arrow function. So that `this` is lexically scoped

Comment: @WaldemarIce you are wrong arrow functions bind the context of `this` lexically so it will work please have a look at this fiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/3ujdud6c/1/

Comment: And what context have enclosing enviroment of setTimeout? You dont know. As setTimeout itself is called in arrow function... Whole example is wrong...

Comment: @WaldemarIce we know the enclosing environment as you said for `setTimeout` is the success call back of get request which is further enclosed in mounted where the value of `this` is the vue instance

Comment: Can you bet on it? I dont see context of whole end method. I dont know where and how is used.

Comment: @WaldemarIce yup i can bet on it ,,,, thats the reason i provided a link to a working fiddle

Comment: But your example have nothing to do with osoda code. You dont know where and how is using end method.

Answer (score 0):

May be you have issue with referencing `this`,Try like this.

```
dataReq.end((err, resp) => {
    resp = JSON.parse(resp.text);
    if (resp.status) {
        var vm = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("Do somthing here");
            // this is now referencing to setTimeout function, so use vm referenced above
            console.log(vm.breadcrumbs[2].path);
        }, 100);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes. I have no problem with setTimeout / setInterval in Vue.

Comment: @WaldemarIce:  ohh sorry , I thought you are OP

Comment: My question? Look for question author again :)

Comment: @WaldemarIce can you say why my answer does not work

Comment: I am not :) Your answer just will work. Vamsi's answer not. He is using arrow function as callback - without particular context.