# location.reload with VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

Is there a way to refresh the Current Router View? Something like location.reload(). But not on the whole page, only in the current path name view.

I searched a lot about it and i tried to do

```
this.$route.router.go
```

/\ This reloads all the page, not good.

I found a very good possible solution [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32106155/can-you-force-vue-js-to-reload-re-render). But when i tried it:

```
vm.$forceupdate
```

**Console.log (vm.$forceUpdate)**

> ƒ () {
>       var vm = this;
>       if (vm._watcher) {
>         vm._watcher.update();
>       }   }

Yes! '**vm**' is already a global variable.
**console.log ( vm )**

> Vue$3 {_uid: 0, _isVue: true, $options: {…}, _renderProxy: Proxy, _self: Vue$3, …}

**Nothing** happens with this function.
Someone knows what is happening or other way to do that?

Thanks!!

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but it's `forceUpdate` not `forceupdate`. And to call it you'd need to do `vm.$forceUpdate()`

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @thanksd I edited my question. Actually nothing happens with this function.

Comment: You say you want to reload the page but not all the page. That's vague. You'll need to be more specific about what you're expecting to happen and what isn't working as expected.

Comment: @ceejayoz  have a menu, and if for example you are on the "Test" page and click on the navigation on the "Test" page (Yes, the same page), I want refresh this "Test" view, but only the view, not the whole page.

Comment: Change the data the component uses and it'll update accordingly. If you want another component to make the change, look into cross-component communication via events or something like Vuex.

Comment: Hmmm i think i want a thing more simple than that... I don't know if i was clearly. I made a plunker to help us: https://plnkr.co/edit/dPWymDU9A8obdisjiwUC?p=preview

Comment: @ceejayoz I understood what you are saying, but i'm making Axious.get to get a JSON, and if there is something new in my Rest API, i have to refresh the View to bring data again.

Answer (score 0):

Everything which is within `data` or `computed` is reactive and will update the view on change. Hence you should store your `JSON` in `data` (or if it's used in store - use `mapState`). If you need more specific answer - please, provide an example.

Comment: Hi Artur.js, yes! I know it. My real problem is because i make a Axios.Get by a Rest API. and when API get a new value, the view will not update, because i have to do a new Axios.Get. That's why i wanted to make a Refresh on view when i click on view on menu.

Comment: How do you know that data on backend has changed? If you have sockets - make another get call on msg. Also you may wanna use one (sockets.io, for example) Otherwise you can make a timeout to retrieve data every n seconds etc.