# Vue: refreshing a route/component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Is there any built-in functionality in Vue that allows for reloading a `component`, in a way that the page won't be reloaded in the browser, and instead the component would be destroyed and recreated again? That said `$router.go()` will not work in this case as it reloads the page in browser instead of the current DOM.

Update:

`$forceUpdate()` also fails as I need everything to be re-initialized again (by letting Vue reinitializing the component instead of doing everything manually).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you force Vue.js to reload/re-render?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32106155/can-you-force-vue-js-to-reload-re-render)

Comment: @JacobGoh: The other post is really useless, had seen it before. and there's no accepted answers in there.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving the component a `:key="uid"` and change `this.uid` variable when you want to update the component. This just has to be something unique and it should mount again. E.g...

```
this.uid = Date.now()
```

Comment: I solved this, by using `v-if` to force re-rendering a component.