# VueJS: How to force recompile of <template> after modifying dom

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In the following single file template, I am loading user cars from a backend, store them inside a state of a store module, and then use the result in this component to build a table.

Action is asynchronous, so I used a watch() to be able to rerender my table each time the list of cars is updated.

**Problem:** Initialization of the table is made from Javascript code, and the second column displays 2 buttons. I would like to do something when the user click on one of those buttons: But @click or  are not recognize here because they are added after the mount of the component.

How can i force the re-render of the component ?

```
<template>
    <div class="col-xl-8">
        <div class="kt-datatable" id="cars_datatable"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions, mapGetters } from "vuex";

export default {
    created: function() {
        this.getUserCars();
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters(["userCars"])
    },
    methods: {
        ...mapActions(["getUserCars"])
    },
    watch: {
        userSites: function() {
            const options = {
                data: {
                    type: "local",
                    source: this.userCars,
                    pageSize: 5
                },
                layout: {
                    theme: "default",
                    class: "",
                    scroll: !1,
                    footer: !1
                },
                sortable: !0,
                pagination: !0,
                columns: [
                    {
                        field: "name",
                        title: "Name"
                    },
                    {
                        field: "Actions",
                        title: "Actions",
                        sortable: false,
                        width: 110,
                        overflow: "visible",
                        autoHide: false,
                        template: function() {
                            return '\
                                <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-sm btn-clean btn-icon btn-icon-md" title="Edit details">\
                                    <i class="la la-edit"></i>\
                                </a>\
                                <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-sm btn-clean btn-icon btn-icon-md" title="Delete">\
                                    <i class="la la-trash"></i>\
                                </a>\
                            ';
                        }
                    }
                ]
            };
            $("#cars_datatable").KTDatatable(options);
        }
    }
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you force Vue.js to reload/re-render?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32106155/can-you-force-vue-js-to-reload-re-render)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are already using JQuery, so the easiest solution is to use the dynamic `jQuery.fn.on` way to register the event handler. That handler will recognize the elements you add dynamically. [Read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)