# Why does the numbering not work for some uses of v-data-table

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

The behavior is, I click the next-page chevron and it loads the correct data from the database and  goes to the next page, but it does not update the pagination text, which still reads `1-10 of 513`.  If I use the prev-page and then next-page, so it reads from the cache, this problem does not occur.  In a very similar component, the problem never occurs.  The code looks like this:

```
QListComponent.vue

<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="items"
  :server-items-length="serverItemsLength"
  :loading="loading"
  @update:options="onOptionsUpdate"
>
...
props: {
   items: Array,
   ...
```

And it is being used in two components:

```
BuildingListComponent.vue

<q-list-component :items="buildings">
 ...
props: {
   buildings: Array as PropType<Building[]>,
   ...
```

and

```
EmployeeListComponent.vue

<q-list-component :items="employees">
 ...
props: {
   employees: {
      type: Array as PropType<Employee[]>,
      required: true,
   ...
```

In the BuildingList, the pagination works fine.  In the EmployeeList, it only works when reading from the cache.  How can this possibly be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don’t be too smug if you figured it out.  I had to cut off hundreds of lines of irrelevant code to reduce it down the skeleton problem you see.

If you didn’t figure it out, the problem was the `employees` prop was *required*, and while the client was loading data from the database, it did not have a value.  The invocation of the BuildingList was done like this:

```
<building-list :buildings="buildingQuery.results" />
```

But that style with the EmployeeList would have resulted in a compiler error (since results might be `Employee[]` or it might be `undefined`), so the line was written like this:

```
<employee-list :employees="employeeQuery.results || []" />
```

Removing the empty list (and the `required:` option that necessitated it) fixed the problem.  I guess that this is quirk of Vuetify, to assume that if the list is empty, we must be at the first page.

(Another contributor had [a similar *seeming* problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59681026/vuetify-data-table-custom-component-does-not-load-beyond-page-1), with an unrelated cause.)

## Or maybe not

In further analysis, I found I was also setting `serverItemsLength` to `undefined` while the query was running.  Whether this was the true cause of the problem or just another cause of the problem, I now lack the energy to investigate.