# What is the best way to refresh my Vue.js Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have on my search page a textbox and search button.

I created a facet using Vue.js. Everything is working at the first time that I search for something , but when I digit another text and search for it, my facet is not being updated with the new values.

I tried to following this, but unsuccessful: https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/

Anyone can save me with that?

```
function CreateFacetSiteSearch(resultsFacet) {
    new Vue({
        el: '#facets',
        data() {
            return {
                facets: resultsFacet.Facets,
                totalresults: resultsFacet.TotalNumberOfResults
            }
        }
    });
}

CreateFacetSiteSearch(results); => I call this function everytime that I search for a new text.

<div class="search-filter-container" id="facets" v-if="totalresults > 0">
   <div class="links-container">
            <a href="#" v-for="item in facets" onclick="CallSearchFacet(this)" :result-field-name="item.Item1" :result-count="item.Item2">{{ item.Item1 }} ({{ item.Item2 }})</a>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: To the Component that you want to refresh you can bind `:key="yourSearchString"`. When the search string changes your component will rerender.

Answer (score 0):

Try this magic spell:

```
vm.$forceUpdate();
```

or

you can also use `:key="someVariableUnderYourControl"` and change the key when you want to component to be completely rebuilt.

reference : [Can you force Vue.js to reload/re-render?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32106155/can-you-force-vue-js-to-reload-re-render)