# Vue rerender component on reset button

Tags: vue.js, button, components, render, vue-reactivity

I have a reset button which reset the state to the initial values. I need to rerender the component with currentTab is there any bet way to do it?

```
<button @click="resetData">reset</button>

<keep-alive>
    <component :is="currentTab"></component>
</keep-alive>

methods: 
resetData() {
    this.$store.dispatch('resetData')
    // re-render component based on the currentTab
    ??
}
```

currentTab I'm getting from the list of tabs:

```
tabs: [One, Two, Three]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you force Vue.js to reload/re-render?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32106155/can-you-force-vue-js-to-reload-re-render)

Comment: unfortunately it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to force a render.  To do so from the parent, set a `key` on the child.  Changing the key will cause the child to rerender:

HTML:

```html
<component :is="currentTab" :key="tabKey"></component>
```

In the parent, define the key as a number:

```js
data() {
  return {
    tabKey: 0
  }
}
```

Change the `key`:

```js
methods: {
  resetData() {
    this.tabKey++;
  }
}
```

Note:  Using `this.$forceUpdate` from within the component will only cause its view to rerender.