# Is there something to auto update this code in vue?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, nuxt.js

I got this button in the navigator that shows up when a user is logged in and when the user logs out the button is gone. But now i need to refresh my page before the button removes/appears. Here is my code:
**Button:**

```
<div v-if="ingelogd">
  <div class="w-2/12 hidden lg:flex" v-for="(data, index) in allIngelogds" :key="index">
    <button @click="uitloggen" class="downloadbtn">
      {{ data.uitloggenKnop }}
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

in `data:()` i return this:

```
ingelogd: false
```

and then i created a `mounted()` function to update if the user is logged in or not:

```
mounted() {
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser
    if(user) {
      this.ingelogd = true;
    }
  },
```

And yes i imported firebase and firebase/auth and `allIngelogds` is a graphql query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use an `onAuthStateChanged` listener instead of the `currentUser`:

```
mounted() {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if(user) {
      this.ingelogd = true;
    }
  });
},
```

The `onAuthStateChanged` listener gets called each time the sign-in state changes, which ensures your `ingelogd` always reflects this state.

For more on this, see the first snippet in the Firebase documentation on [getting the currently signed in user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user).

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40586872/8647537

Checkout the answer above. The lazy way or not very good approach will be

> vm.$forceUpdate();

it is not good approach though. Read more in mentioned link.