# Uncaught TypeError: window.reload is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to print an image from inside a div, the code runs ok but when the print dialog pops up, I would like the page to stay the same while actually it is showing only the picture as the `window.reload` doesn't work for some reasons. The javascript is telling me in console `"Uncaught TypeError: window.reload is not a function"`but i don't understand why.

```
  function printDiv(printableArea) {
    var printContents = document.getElementById("printableArea").innerHTML;
    var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
    window.print();
    window.close();
    window.reload();
  }
```

Click to print

```
<input type="button" onclick="printDiv('printableArea')" value="print a div!" />
```

Comment: Because there is no such method on window object. There is `location.reload()`.

Comment: location.reload() might work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reload a page using Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715047/how-to-reload-a-page-using-javascript)

Comment: thanks, just tried window.location.reload(true); but yet the page prints the image itself without any style and the print dialog popsIn, then when i close the popUp the page reloads. i would like not to have that page

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason you are getting the error is that there is no `window.reload()` method. You might want to use [`location.reload()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload) to reload the page instead.

Comment: just tried, thanks. Yet when the dialog pops up, the document shows only the image and not the actual page. I thought the print dialog would keep the page that's why i am reloading. Now ok your answer is correct and I will accept it. Thakns

Comment: @rob.m could you clarify the issue you're having?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if there's such function, Try `location.reload()`

[details](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp)

Answer (score 3):

use `location.reload();` or `window.location.reload(true);`

https://webplatform.github.io/docs/apis/location/reload/

Answer (score 0):

Use this to go to particular URL

```
window.location=url;
```