# How to make location.reload() work on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button which, when pressed, should reload the page. I use [`location.reload()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload) to perform the action (following the answers on [how to reload a page with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715047/how-to-reload-a-page-using-javascript)).

The code I used (available on [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/WoJWoJ/pen/YwqXyj))

HTML

```
<button class="reload">update</button>
<div class="radio"></div>
```

JS

```
$('.reload').click(function() {
  alert('clicked');
  location.reload(true);
});

window.onload = function() {
  $('.radio').text($.now());
};
```

The pages initially loads with the current Epoch counter but clicking the button does not update it.

I also tried to use `$(document).ready()` in case `window.onload` would not be triggered by `location.reload()` - same result.

How can I force a page reload in this scenario?

Comment: did you try window.location??

Comment: This will work :
$('.reload').click(function() {
  location.href=location.href;
});

Comment: Your posted code works as expected. Now i'm really not sure what are you expecting?! Is click event fired or not?

Comment: yes. your Posted code is working. value changed whenever i clicked on Button.

Comment: Can you get alert message

Comment: @A.Wolff: It probably works as expected. What *I* expected is to have the timestamp updated when clicking the button (it is not).

Comment: @WoJ It works there: http://jsfiddle.net/enf98tdf/  In your codepen, it doesn't work because the onload event is never fired.

Comment: @A.Wolff: indeed it does. This is interesting because it does not in codepen.io, neither in NetBeans. I will try the other solutions across JSFiddle and Netbeans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try history.go(0);

```js
$('.reload').click(function() {
  //window.location.reload(true);
  history.go(0);
});

window.onload = function() {
  $('.radio').text($.now());
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="reload">update</button>
<div class="radio"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to use jQuery to do this.

Try this:

```
<button class="reload" onclick="location.reload()">update</button>
<div class="radio"></div>
```

Comment: True, but I load jQuery anyway (for other parts of the code) and wanted to understand what I did wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This may work fine:

```
$('.reload').click(function() {
    location.href=location.href;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

What's the issue?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.reload').on('click', function() {
    window.location.reload();
  })
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gzo8kr0u/

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$( ".reload" ).click(function(ev) {  
    ev.preventDefault();  
    location.reload(); 
});
```