# How to reload the page when asked for Geolocation

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML5 asking for geolocation.

Here is how it looks like:

[image]

My question is: How can i reload the page when the user accepts to Allow sharing his location? Is there any javascript which can do that ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you reload the page, it's just going to ask the user to confirm geolocation again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reload a page using Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715047/how-to-reload-a-page-using-javascript)

Comment: XY problem here. Why do you want to do so ?

Answer (score 2):

Just reload page when location got, to prevent infinite reload, check with cookie

```
window.onload = function() {      
  var geoSuccess = function(position) {           
     $.cookie("position_latitude", position.coords.latitude);
     $.cookie("position_longitude", position.coords.longitude);
     document.location.reload(true);
  };
  if ($.cookie("position_longitude", undefined))
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function() {
    window.location.reload();
});
```

You have access to a callback function when asking for the location, just reload the page inside the callback

Comment: You mean this code will reload the page when i accept to share location with the browser ?

Comment: Basically, when you call the function to display this prompt asking the user for it's location. once it's accepted, the function that you pass as a parameter will be called, so you can do anything inside. It will also be called if the user already accepted sharing his location to your website/app