# Codeigniter refresh $this->load->view()

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am passing a parameter to my view, and it needs to be refreshed so the data will be populated, so how to refresh my page after when I loaded it?

```
$this->load->view('portal/view_parent', $data, 'refresh');
```

Comment: U can also use redirect method

Comment: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#redirect

Comment: You may need to use a java script window refresh if you do not want to use codeigniter redirect refresh http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715047/how-to-reload-a-page-using-javascript

Comment: why not use jquery ajax?

Comment: Could please explain what is issue here you are facing, as I know if call controller/method from URL it will going refresh the page. So, here could please let me when an why you refresh so that someone can give you better option.

Answer (score -1):

Jus try with

```
   redirect('controllername/methodname');
```

It refresh the whole page.

Or if want to refresh specific portion of a page u should use ajax call and append to div.

Comment: I dont want to redirect it because I am passing a parameter to the view

Comment: Post ur full controller code @aronccs then i help you better :)