# GAE : How to refresh page after submitting form on GAE?

Tags: forms, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, page-refresh

I have a form on a page and submit the details of the form on the click of the submit button and want to refresh the page after the object is added to the datastore. I read online that this could be because of the datastore's Eventual Consistency but can't seem to figure out a way to achieve the desired result(refreshing the page).

```
class AddUpdateProfile(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        #This will be used to add/update profile in a datastore. Will be called when the user clicks on submit button on the Profile Page
        template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('profile.html')
        error = None
        name = self.request.get('name')
        designation = self.request.get('designation')
        salary = self.request.get('salary')
        currency = self.request.get('currency')
        logging.info("Name = "+name)
        logging.info("Designation = "+designation)
        logging.info("Salary = "+salary)
        logging.info("Currency = "+currency)

        profile = UserProfile(parent=userProfile_key(users.get_current_user().email()))
        profile.name = name
        profile.designation = designation
        profile.salary = int(salary)
        profile.currency = currency
        profile.email = str(users.get_current_user().email())
        profile.put()

        #Go back to main page. TODO : Change this to update 
        self.redirect('/profile')

class Profile(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        logging.info("Inside Profile Page")
        user = users.get_current_user()

        if user:
            profileInfo = getProfileInformation(user.email())
            logging.info("Found a user inside Profile Page")
            url = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
            if profileInfo is None or not profileInfo:
                logging.info("Email = "+user.email())
                logging.info("Profile Info not found")
                template_values = {
                'user': user.nickname(),
                'url': url
                }
            else:
                logging.info("Profile Info found")
                template_values = {
                'user': user.nickname(),
                'url': url,
                'name' : profileInfo[0].name,
                'designation' : profileInfo[0].designation,
                'salary' : profileInfo[0].salary,
                'currency' : profileInfo[0].currency
                }


            template_values = template_values
            template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('profile.html')
            self.response.write(template.render(template_values))
        else:
            logging.info("User not found. Loading Landing page")
            template_values = {
                'url' : users.create_login_url(self.request.uri)
            }
            template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('landing.html')
            self.response.write(template.render(template_values))


class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        logging.info("Inside MainPage")
        user = users.get_current_user()
        if user:
            logging.info("Found a user inside MainPage")
            url = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
            url_linktext = 'SIGN OUT'
            template_values = {
            'user': user.nickname(),
            'url': url,
            'userPage' : "no",
            'url_linktext': url_linktext,
            }
            template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('index.html')
            self.response.write(template.render(template_values))
        else:
            logging.info("User not found. Loading Landing page")
            template_values = {
                'url' : users.create_login_url(self.request.uri)
            }
            template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('landing.html')
            self.response.write(template.render(template_values))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
    ('/profile', Profile),
    ('/addProfile', AddUpdateProfile)
], debug=True)
```

It would be great if someone could have a look at the code and give me some input on how to resolve the issue.

Any help is really appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: You haven't described your problem. *What* is because of eventual consistency?

Comment: I think I can provide an answer but as pointed by Daniel you need to describe your issue more precisely and also to make the questions shorter - there is no need for people to see all the code (like salary, currency. etc). Try to make your code as short as possible and to the point. Once edited I can provide an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but in general, if you want to refresh the page, you should do it using Javascript/JQuery on your page.

Have your endpoint send back a JSON response back to the '/profile'.  The response should look something like:

```
{"success":"success"}
```

Or if, you need to send an error message:

```
{"error": "insert error message here"}
```

Your Javascript and/JQuery should then check if "error" is in the response.  If it is throw an error message, otherwise, refresh the page.

[How to reload a page using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715047/how-to-reload-a-page-using-javascript)