# window.reload() doesn't reload my page

Tags: javascript, reload

```
     function theLast(){

             if (document.getElementById('dont').checked) {
             document.getElementById('dont').checked=false;}
             else if(document.getElementById('know').checked){
                 document.getElementById('know').checked=false;}
             else if(document.getElementById('master').checked){

                 document.getElementById('master').checked=false;}
                 else {
                 document.getElementById('ans').reset();}
      document.getElementById("pop2").style.display = 'none';
       document.getElementById("myPopup").style.display = 'none';
       document.getElementById("pop3").style.display = 'none';


        document.getElementById("pop4").style.display = 'block';
         document.getElementById('pop4').style.position = "absolute";
         document.getElementById('pop4').style.top = '250px';
        document.getElementById('pop4').style.left = '250px';
        setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('pop4').className = 'waa';

   }, 2500);



window.location.reload();


 }
```

i want to reload my page at the end of this function
tried window.location.reload()
location.reload(true)

is there any other way i can reload my page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reload a page using Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715047/how-to-reload-a-page-using-javascript)

Comment: 1. Clean up your code. 2. I can’t spot `window.reload` nor `window.location.reload` (which would be correct) anywhere in your code.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the code where you're calling `window.location.reload`.  That might be why its not working.

Comment: "reloads the resource from the current URL". See [`location.reload()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload).

Comment: see the edited code, even that is not working. i am running on local host

Comment: If you're going to edit your question, please reformat it. Are you sure you are calling `theLast()`? By the way if you're going to reload the page anyway, why are you doing all the stuff above the call to `reload`?

Comment: yeah. im calling the function theLast() . I did all those because i could'nt refresh the page

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3715123/3206247 and the comment of this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3715071/3206247

Comment: Fire up your debugger, and place a breakpoint on the `window.location.reload` line. Make sure it reaches there. Then step over the line. Your browser will reload. Most likely, you will find that control never reaches that line, because of some other error in your logic.

Comment: You didn't provided your browser versions, but I've made this fiddle and it is fully functional https://jsfiddle.net/dj7c7q0o/

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the support for `location.reload` but why don't you try this:

`window.location.href = window.location.href;`

Comment: What are you sure about?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I meant "what are you NOT sure about?".

Comment: The browser support for the method. Worked here, but I don't know about the OP's browser, because `location.reload()` should work according to this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location

Comment: `window.reload` has been supported in all browsers since time immemorial.

Comment: `window.reload` is not a function

Comment: I meant `location.reload`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#something').click(function() {
location.reload();
});
```

**Add this In Your Script**

Comment: Why do I need to wrap this in a `setTimeout`?