# Php and javascript failing to reload page and jump to location

Tags: javascript

I have been struggling with page reloads

I have a form that will submit data regardless of the line on the table that is updated.

When the form reloads, I can either get the page to reload the whole page or jump to an anchor, but not both.

The first part is
form
hidden value (with anchor) this works

On button click call function

function is in php with :

```
// this code will show editWonLost.php#123456 but does not reload
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>location.hash='$NeedToUpdate'; document.location = 'editWonLost.php'+location.hash</script>"; 

// this code will show editWonLost.php#$NeedToUpdate
echo '<script type="text/javascript">location.hash="$NeedToUpdate"; document.location = "editWonLost.php"+location.hash</script>'; 

// this code will refresh the page but not got to anchor location
echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.location = "editWonLost.php"</script>';
```

The goal is to try get the page to reload and then jump to the location

Comment: Try `window.location = "\"editWonLost.php#".$NeedToUpdate."\"";`

Answer (score 0):

Calling `window.location.reload()` after setting the hash value should work. Your code would then be:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>location.hash='$NeedToUpdate'; location.reload();</script>";
```

---

### Update:

If your goal is to redirect the user to another page after submitting the form, try something like the following (untested!):

```
header('Location: editWonLost.php' . $NeedToUpdate);
```

Obviously, you have to check if the form has been submitted, and only redirect the user if it has.

Comment: Hi Maxkl I have tried the code, It reloads and stays at the location where it should be, but goes in a constant loop. page keeps refreshing. I had this before when using location.reload.

Comment: Well, you should only reload if the user isn't on the page you are redirecting to. A better solution would probably be to do a redirect directly in PHP, I'll update my answer for more info.

Comment: Only solution working for me is to Redirect to a new page that the redirects back to my page. The data is then reloaded on the page load and then the jump to function works afterwards

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the javascript documentation for `location.reload()`

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp

So, your PHP could look like:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>location.hash='$NeedToUpdate'; document.location = 'editWonLost.php'+location.hash;  window.location.reload();</script>"; // this code will show editWonLost.php#123456
```

You can see this related question, as well:

[How to reload a page using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715047/how-to-reload-a-page-using-javascript)

Comment: Hi maxkl. I have tried the code and it is reloading the page every second.

Comment: I have tried the following from your link. window.locations.replace() will reload the page to the location but does not refresh my data. i then tried with windows.locations.assign(). same thing. If i click on my link multiple times after the second link it shows the change previously.