# Refresh site - if no activity

Tags: html

I am having a touch screen with some very basic html pages. But if there is no activity for maybe 5 minutes, it should reload the main page again. So if I the main index.html page where there are links to siteb.html and sitec.html - it should after few minutes without activity load main.html again, even if standing on sitec.html

So it is not just a refresh of the site, but a load of the main page if there is no activity

Is there any scipt for this or an example I can try and test ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reload a page using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715047/how-to-reload-a-page-using-javascript)

Comment: Please provide an example of what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="text">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Reload page</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    location.reload();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't exactly meet the OP's requirements.

Comment: using this you can reload the page, for no activity you can make time out function which depends on your framework

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code also which includes time interval that means after 300 seconds page will be refreshed.

```
         setInterval(function() {
              window.location.reload();
            }, 300000);
```