# How can I reload the page after confirmation of file export in Datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am following this example:

[https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html)

I want if I confirm the file exporting , the page will reload. How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reload a page using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715047/how-to-reload-a-page-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the button's action. Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#example').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        {//Start the creation of the button
          extend: "csv",//It's a button that export the table dtat into a CSV file
          text: "export and relode",//The text of the button
          action: function(e, dt, button, config) {
                //The action of the button
                $.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.csvHtml5.action.call(this, e, dt, button, config);//Export the data
                window.location.reload(false);//Relode the page
                    }
        }
    ]
  });

});
```

Here is a working **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eg7x7ygh/)**