# How to refresh the page

Tags: javascript

```js
<script>
$('#showselectedpages').on('click','#editselection',function(e){
 //alert('edit');
 e.preventDefault();
 var id =$(this).val();
 var company=$('#cname').val();
 $.ajax({
 type:'POST',
 url:'mainquery_files/showselection.php',
 data:{mode:"showsingledata",company:company,id:id},
 success:function(data){  
 var parsed = $.parseJSON(data);
 $('#field1').attr('value',parsed.category);
 $('#field2').attr('value',parsed.display_name);
    
     $.ajax({
                        type: 'post',
                        url:'selectPage.php',                        
                        data: {depart:parsed.category},
                        success:function(response){ 
//alert(data);      
                          $('#page_name').empty();
                              var parsed = $.parseJSON(response);
                              $.each(parsed,function(i,parsed){                             
                         $('#page_name').append($('<option/>',{ value: parsed.pages, text: parsed.pages }));
                              });
                         }
      
     });
  
 $('#privilage').attr('value',parsed.privilage);
 $('#hidid').attr('value',parsed.id);
 $("#field1").attr('readonly','readonly'); 
 
 }

 });
 
});


 });
 
});
<script>
```

I am a beginner in javascript.
This is the code for editing the form.I have to refresh the page after editing.
How could i accomplish this? .I tried a lot but window doesn't refreshed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reload a page using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715047/how-to-reload-a-page-using-javascript)

Comment: Why refresh after doing AJAX data processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript provides a handy function called reload on to the location object, you can use it like this:

```
window.location.reload()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `location.reload();` in your success code/wherever you want to refresh

Answer (score 0):

You can use `location.reload()` to refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

You can use `location.reload()` after successful submission of the form. If you just want to empty all fields you can use `var anyField= "";`

Comment: I don't have your code sample. But you must have to after the successful submission of the form, where you are getting success. The above code just reloads the page and nothing else so wherever you put it will reload it.