# How to reload page after pressing enter in chat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So here is my code. When I press the button with mouse it reloads page but, when I press enter key its not refreshing. Any ideas how to do it?

```
 <template lang="html">

        <div class="chat-composer">

        <input maxlength="180" type="text" placeholder="mesajınızı yazınız"  v-model="messageText" @keyup.enter="sendMessage">i

        <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="sendMessage" onClick="window.location.reload();>Gönder</button>
        </div>

    </template>
```

here is full the code I use. So im not the expert.. I need help about it

```
<template lang="html">
    <div class="chat-composer">
    <input maxlength="180" type="text" placeholder="mesajınızı yazınız"  v-model="messageText"
    @keyup.enter="sendMessage">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="sendMessage" onClick="window.location.reload();"
    >Gönder</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                messageText: ''
            }
        },
        methods: {
            sendMessage(){
                this.$emit('messagesent',{
                message: this.messageText,
                user: {
                    name: $('.navbar-right .dropdown-toggle').text()
                }
                });
                this.messageText = '';
            },

        },

    }
</script>
```

Comment: What language is it? Does not look like actual HTML, even though similar to it.

Comment: @keyup.enter = window.location.reload(); how i can add it with proper syntax? I thought this could work.

Comment: its bit mixed, vue, html, java i am not even sure. cuz I just copied these codes. so thats why I ask

Comment: as i see form the code  this is a Vuejs? framework for building user interfaces

Comment: the next question is, where are you going to use this? Does it live inside a browser environment. Does your code have control over reloading the whole window?

Comment: just use the Key Modifiers for instance v-on:keyup.enter="window.location.reload()"

Comment: yeah, I use it as chat already, i am adding full code.

Comment: im trying @TahaAzzabi

Comment: Consider using ajax to reload just the portion of html you need, instead of reloading the entire page everytime.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reload a page using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715047/how-to-reload-a-page-using-javascript)

Comment: well I tried some of these also but still not working.. any other ideas? :/

Answer (score 1):

You are using Vue.js, if so you can do something like this

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" v-on:keyup.enter="window.location.reload()" 
 @click="sendMessage" onClick="window.location.reload();>Gönder</button>
```

You can check the Key Modifiers here  the https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html

Comment: I think we are close to the end. Mouse click works but , enter is still not working..

Comment: I tried many different combinations... none of them is working.. peh any ideas now?

Comment: you can also use `@keypress.enter="something"` , but i wonder why you need to refresh page that will en all websocket connexion if you have it, and it will refresh the state and the reactive data if you don't use persist

Comment: so its like a real time chat normally(which is not working in my case), so that s why its not refreshing the page.