# Typescript, Angular - how to reload website after time

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a problem. I'd like to reload website after 5 minutes and that is my question, how to reload website in Typescript/Angular application?

Comment: You could use `setTimeout` and then use the Router call your home route with a random parameter, which makes the site reload. But why would you need to reload? Couldn't you use WebSockets?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reload a page using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715047/how-to-reload-a-page-using-javascript)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your main app component file, under ngOnInit(), you could add a setTimeout method that reloads every 5 minutes like so:

```
ngOnInit() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    window.location.reload();
  }, 300000); // Activate after 5 minutes.
}
```

Though I don't know your situation, I would highly advise against doing this. Most likely, whatever you are trying to accomplish, can probably be done in a better way than refreshing the page. That's just my opinion. For me as a User, i'd be really annoyed if i'm browsing a site and it just randomly refreshes.

Comment: Is there a way for me to set specific date? For example I want the page to be able to reload at 14 o'clock.

Comment: It's not set timeout it setInterval so that , this will work on each 5 minutes interval


             ngOnInit() {
                     setInterval(() => {
                    window.location.reload();
                     }, 300000); // Activate after 5 minutes.
                                                }

Answer (score 2):

use `window.location.reload();` to refresh the page