# Trouble with continous refreshing page

Tags: javascript, php, page-refresh

When I try to run this script:

```
<form class="form-inline" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
    <button type="submit" name="buttonSubmit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['buttonSubmit'])) {
    unset($_POST['buttonSubmit']);
    echo "<script>alert(".isset($_POST['buttonSubmit']).")</script>";
    echo "<script>location.reload(true);</script>";
  }
?>
```

As a result, the page is refreshing in an infinite loop.

What is the reason?

How do I refresh my website only once?

Comment: it's duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715047/how-to-reload-a-page-using-javascript

Comment: Change `location.reload(true);` to `window.location.href = '';`

Comment: Is it `alerting` every time?

Comment: @Mr. Blue Thank you, its working

Comment: @Ajax. Yes, it alerting every time.

Comment: i updated my answer with yet another solution, which might be even better. That one I use all the time, making sure users doesn't submit repeatedly

Comment: This looks like you are attempting to prevent a page from being cached; it's a horrible hack and the wrong approach. Just use appropriate HTTP cache-control headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This helped me:

Change `location.reload(true);` to `window.location.href = '';`

Answer (score 1):

When you use `location.reload(true);`, you do the same, programmatically, as clicking on the browsers "Refresh/Reload" button.

This will generate yet another "submit", over and over, hence always make the statement `isset($_POST['buttonSubmit'])` be true.

Here are a couple solutions:

- `location.href = 'page-to-load';`
- [`location.assign('page-to-load');`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign)
- [`location.replace('page-to-load');`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace)

  <sup>The `Location.replace()` method replaces the current resource, and after that the current page will not be saved in
  session `History`, meaning the user won't be able to use the back button either,
  to navigate to it and cause a repeated "submit", which normally will occur.</sup>

Note, if the `'page-to-load'` is the same being already loaded, you can use `location.href`, e.g.

```
location.replace(location.href);
```

---

Yet another way would be, instead of rely on a client side script, to do a `response redirect` upon a form submittion, server side.

- [How to make a redirect in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)