# Reload or Refresh a page using Jquery from local machine

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html document on my local machine, I created a button using JQuery and set an on click for the button. When the button is clicked, I want the current index.html page refresh.

This following is in the script tags:

```
    var refreshButton = '<button id="refresh"> Refresh </button>';
    $body.append(refreshButton);
    $('#refresh').click(function(){
      refresh(forceGet);
    });
```

i tried, `location.refresh();` & `window.location.refresh();` & `refresh();` but they didnt work.

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console? `window.location.reload(true);` will work.

Comment: Have you looked at this answer on how to refresh a page using javascript: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715047/how-to-reload-a-page-using-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$body.append(refreshButton);
```

needs to be

```
$('body').append(refreshButton);
```

and window.location.reload(true); should work.  Try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('body').append('<button id="refresh"> Refresh </button>');
   $('#refresh').click(function(){
      window.location.reload(true);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [window.location.reload()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload).

```js
$('document').ready(() => {
    $('#last-date').html(new Date())
    $('#refresh').on('click', () => {
        console.log('Refreshing...')
        window.location.reload(true)
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="refresh">Refresh</button>
<p>Last loaded at <span id="last-date"></span></p>
```

Comment: i had .refresh instead of reload