# Is it possible to reload page Url without change request Url?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ado.net

I have a page with a button that if clicked on it, a function is called that creates a pdf and it is opened in a new tab.
Now after clicking this button, I want to reload the current page then pdf file open in a new window.
How can I do this action without change request url?

I try to use below code but it change the url of new tab:

> if (Request.UrlReferrer != null) Response.Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a simple JavaScript to reload current page completely

Have a look at this answer:

[How to reload a page using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24111334/854405)

Comment: thank you for your answer. but I can't do it in javascript code; because I do some action in controller and I want to reload after these actions. So I think it should be done in c# code.

Comment: When you use ajax you should reload page in JavaScript, there is no way to reload.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Request.UrlReferrer.ToString()

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I try it before but it change my current url that has been opened for show pdf and I don't want to change the request url