# window.location.reload() doenot working after click function in popup Chrome extention

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, window, reload

i want to reload window when user click on the icon. i tried to use window.location.reload() but its doenot work and i dont know why. if you have any case to resolve this issue please write about this. thanks for help
popup-js:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
   let  icons =  document.getElementsByClassName('icon');
   for( let icon of icons){
    icon.addEventListener('click',function(){
       let imgSrc = icon.src;
       chrome.storage.local.set({key: imgSrc});
       window.location.reload();

     })
   } 
})
```

Comment: Try to pass `false` as a parameter of `window.location.reload`, also, you need to `return false;` after that, because you try to reload from event listener.

Comment: Also, check out this answer for more information - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715047/how-to-reload-a-page-using-javascript

Comment: i tried but still not working