# How to reload page after script on Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a newbee in javascript and i need to refresh page when script is done:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm() {
      var x = document.forms["myForm"]["Hostname"].value;
      if (x == "" || x == null) {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return document.location.reload(true);
      }
    }
    </script>
```

But i don't understand how to make it work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reload a page using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715047/how-to-reload-a-page-using-javascript)

Comment: can it be used in return: ?
I need to reload page if value is empty. 
Thanks

Comment: You don't need to return it. Maybe your `x` is `undefined`?

Comment: maybe this one helps: `if(!x || x.trim() === "")` also `location` doesn't belong to `document`. use directly `location.reload();`

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm() {
      var x = document.forms["myForm"]["Hostname"].value;
      if (x == "" || x == null) {
        alert("Please specify a FQDN of your host");
        window.location.reload(true);
        return false;
      This one works fine. Thanks to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["myForm"]["Hostname"].value;
  if (x == "" || x == null) {
    alert("Please specify a FQDN of your host");
    window.location.reload(true);
    return false;
 </script>
```

This one works fine. Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

try it

```js
window.location.reload(true);
```