# How to load a PHP-File in Java-Script code?

Tags: javascript, php, reload

Hello I have a PHP file named test.php. For this I have the following code:

```
  <body>
            function writeData(){
              
              firebase.database().ref("User").set({
              name: document.getElementById("nameField").value,
              age: document.getElementById("ageField")
              });

              ***Here the test.php file should be reloaded***
              }
              
            </script>
                <div class="box">
<center>            <div class="button">
                    
                        <button onclick = "writeData()"> Submit </button>

                    </div>
                </div>
</center>

 </body>
```

How can I reload my test.php file in the Javascript code?
I would be happy about answers

Comment: `window.location.reload(true);`.

Comment: Don't reload; just update.

Comment: @IMSoP I've reopened the question. Though the title is a bit confusing, the issue here is not in understanding the difference between server-side and client-side code. The text in the question says, that the provided code is in `test.php`, and the actual problem is described in the code itself ("_Here the test.php file should be reloaded_").

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reload a page using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715047/how-to-reload-a-page-using-javascript)

Comment: do you need to get some variable values from server-side?

Comment: @ÄsiriLäkmäl yes from the Firebase

Comment: @NilsSchmidt i think better if you make ajax request with json data format.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

with refresh

```js
 location.reload();
```

if you want to load the file without refresh, you should use Ajax

workflow example
with jquery

```js
$('#yourdiv_id').load('page.php');
```