# asp.net mvc refresh view from Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the Index page where there is an Html.ActionLink.
This link is calling a function in the controller and creating a csv file into the local user drive.
at the end of the function, i am trying to refresh the page,
after the file was downloaded.
I tried "return View()" And redirect, both doesn't work since i'm already on the index page
and i want to stay there.
Any ideas?
Html:

```
<div class="col-6 text-right">
    <p>@Html.ActionLink("Export Unshipped To CSV", "ExportToCSV")</p>
</div>
```

Thank you very much! :)

Comment: I don't think there's a way to know when the file has been downloaded so there's no event that you can hook into. You could just use JS to reload the page after X seconds - [as shown in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27835326/2008963)

Comment: How can i activate the JS Function after the link was pressed?

Comment: You need to add a binding on your div element. Look at the fiddler link on the post I linked you to :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `return RedirectToAction("Index");` for reloading Index page.

Comment: Hi,
No, This doesn't work since i'm already at Index view, it won't refresh.

Comment: @Kobi Could you please attach a sample Github repository or put all of your codes according to this problem here which shows this issue? Actually, this should works fine.