# Express not rendering page after a POST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

My goal is to have an onclick function send a post request to delete an HTML li off the page. The post request uses a mongoose function to delete the data then I want the page to be reloaded so the user sees the new page without the item they deleted. The deletion works fine however I have to refresh the page to see it be deleted. There isn't any error messages.

garage.jade

```
doctype html 
html(lang='en')
  head  
    script 
       include ../Scripts/garage_scripts.js 
    
  body 
    h1 Welcome to The Garage
      h2= title
      ul
      - for (let i=0; i<list_o_cars.length; i++)
        li(onclick='delete_car(this)', id="cars")= list_o_cars[i]
```

garage_scripts.js

```
function delete_car(target) {
  const data = {
    car: target.innerHTML,
  };

  const url = "http://localhost:3000/car_module/delete";
  let request_param = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Accept: "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
  };

  fetch(url, request_param);
}
```

controller.js

```
exports.delete = function (req, res, next) {
res.send("hi") 
[enter image description here][1]//this would be a render but I am just testing to see if it will reload or redirect to a new page
```

this is the image of the request preview [image: img]

Comment: The page is not going to re-render by itself. You either have to reload the page manually with javascript (probably not a good approach) or delete the ```li``` with javascript and when the user eventually reloads the page the data will be gone.

Comment: What are you trying to do after sending response "res.send('hi') ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since fetch returns a promise, you can resolve it with .then() and reload the page.

```
fetch(url, request_param).then(function(res) { 
    window.location.reload();
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just add `window.location.reload();` after fetch().
Someone did a much better job of explaining this than I am, [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715047/how-to-reload-a-page-using-javascript)