SweetAlert2 and Confirm dialog, how to execute action after an jQuery $.ajax call is executed?
I need to reload the page if a $.ajax call was successful (data.error is undefined). I am using jQuery and SweetAlert2 to display the confirmation dialog nicely and this is how my code looks like:
$(function () {
    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Are you sure you want to continue?',
        text: 'Are you sure you want to remove the selected files?',
        icon: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
        cancelButtonText: 'No',
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.isConfirmed) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost:8080',
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.error) {
                        // show error message here

                        return false;
                    }

                    location.reload();
                }
            })
        }
    });
})

As you can see I am executing the AJAX request when the user clicks the YES button from the SweetAlert2` confirm dialog.
The AJAX call is being done properly and it does not fail (data.error is undefined). The code should not enter in the if conditional and should reload the page but the reload is not happening and I am not sure what I am missing.
If I execute the AJAX call outside of the SweetAlert2 it works as expected and the page gets reloaded.
Can I get some help? Do you see something weird in my solution?

What is location ? As in, does window.location work? Maybe you've overwritten location.

@0stone0 is a short version of window.location see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3715123/719427 also as I mentioned, outside of the SweetAlert2 code works meaning location.reload works just fine

Thats why I suggested to use window.location.reload()

@0stone0 yeah, nop, is not working either. I have added a breakpoint in that line in the Chrome Developer Tools and code never gets there

The AJAX call is being done properly and it does not fail (data.error is undefined) - result.error will only be set if your server sets it and returns a 200 (which it probably should not) and everything else is ok (eg no timeout, JSON formatted correctly).  The success: callback is only called if the ajax call completes successfully - you're not actually checking if the ajax call failed, only if the server said there wasn't an error.   Add the error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { callback and check for ajax errors.  Check the browser network tab.

@fdomn-m you were right, adding the error callback allow me to find out that something else seems to be happening and the backend is screwing the response .... 'parsererror' SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input. Upon checking the backend I could not find any errors. I went back to the JS code and remove this from the $.ajax call: dataType: 'json', and everything worked as expected. Which makes me ask: if I set the dataType: 'json' do I need to send a JSON back all the time? is that how it works? Because if so I am not sending any JSON when the operation success.

jquery $.ajax - dataType The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it.   If you set this to dataType: "text" then your result will be the plain text and you can console.log(result) to see the value to help determine what's going on.   If you do set dataType:'json' then you must return JSON as jquery will always attempt to parse it, and fail if it's not actually valid JSON.

I am not sending any JSON when the operation success - probably easiest to always return JSON.
